# Optional Arguments in Commands

Tags: javascript, discord.js

**EDIT**
I doubt if you can find a correct answer below since this question is too general. And the answer posted by me will most likely only work for that cmd handler and the version this was written for is v12

--Original Question--

how do I make the options like ?d and ? f  optional and the order want matter but it will create the embed on the given options

'example: .embed ?d description: this will create an embed with only a description'

I have already tried but I messed up here is the code [Removed for private reasons]

but this outputs this : [removed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i fixed it my self : )

i splited the args by (?) and went through each value to see if the args have the needed options

here is what I did for future reference :

```
let text = args.join(' ')

const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
let errrors = []

if(!text) return message.channel.send('Error')
let tex = text.split('?')


tex.forEach(async e => { .........


 if(e.toLowerCase().startsWith('d')) {
   let description = e.replace('d', '')
     if(description.length == 0) {
       return await errrors.push('Description option was given but no description was given!!')
     } else {
      await Embed.setDescription(description)
     }
  } else if(e.toLowerCase().startsWith('t')) ........


}

// then 

if(errrors.length > 0) {
  let errr = errrors
   Embed.setTitle('Following errors occured while constructing your embed')
Embed.setDescription(errr)
  return message.channel.send(Embed)
} else {

message.channel.send(Embed)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is : go in your main file(like index.js) and set in top of code this :

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
```

Then where command 'embed' is you need to set this :

```
if(command === 'embed'){
          client.commands.get('embed').execute(message, args, Discord);
```

Then in your command folder you will make a file named embed.js . In embed.js you need to set this code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'embed',
    description: 'Embed Test',
    execute(message, args, Discord){
        const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Your Title')
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setFooter('Some Footer here', 'another footer here' )
        .setDescription('> ?testa\n' + '> ?testb\n' + '> testc');
        message.delete();
        message.channel.send(newEmbed);
    }

});
```

And you get only the description after command and message with command ([prefix]embed) will delete after you post it !

Comment: hmmm no, i meant it as a command you do,
.embed ?d description, and I have a command handler setup.

Comment: i don't understand what you want to do . Please give more details!

Comment: sorry if i cant make it clear, but I edited the question see now

Comment: i still dont understand mate! You want a command that will send an embed with a description , right ?